# Ammo.js / Bullet Physics - saving keyframes for "baked" animation

Tags: javascript, three.js, bulletphysics, ammo.js

I have an animation that involves a large number of colliding rigid bodies and a height field. Because the animation does not have to be dynamically calculated, I simulate it offline and save the resulting animation as keyframes. The live version tweens the keyframe data and accounts for the downward acceleration of gravity. (this is all using three.js and ammo.js)

Things are working well except for some pesky issues. One of the issues relates to keyframes and rotation revolutions. I record a keyframe when there is a change in velocity (collision), but for the tweening to work I have to account for the number of full revolutions an objects does. `getRotation()` returns results in range of 2 PI. Does Bullet store this anywhere? I have been mucking with using the velocity of last keyframe to determine extra rotation cycles, and it's been ugly.

I am wondering if Bullet stores the revolutions anywhere.  ...Or, if there is a system out there for recording keyframes that I should be using instead. I feel as though I am re-inventing a wheel, but googling suggests there are no great options, i.e. 
http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?271338-bullet-physics-branch-baking-keyframes

Thanks a bunch!!